# Writing and saving a file and opening it

Tags: java, android

So my main idea is opening a uploaded file in res/raw directory, edit it, save and reopen it. But i also need a function to set default (overwrite csv file with the default one), so i need 2 files, the default one and the other one I edit and read.
Is it true that u can't write a file and store it in res/raw directory? If yes, then what's the best way to do it in this case? Should i save everything in internal/external storage and open later it from here?

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOut = openFileOutput("C:\\Users\\textfile.csv", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOut);
    for (int b = 0; b < test.AddName("Karlos",1,1,vardadienas).size(); b++) {
        outputWriter.write(test.AddName("Karlos",1,1,vardadienas).get(b));
        outputWriter.write("\n");
    }
    outputWriter.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use **getResources() method** and read the file (uploaded in resources folder), save it in a list array, edit the array and then i should save, but where? And also why this method doesnt create any file? I have set the path, but it doesn't create anything..

I also get this error:

> at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:201)
>   at com.example.firstapp.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)

Comment: It seems pretty strange to open a file on C:/ on Android no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to res/raw as it is part of the apk file.

But you can read from res/raw ant then write a copy of the file in the app's local and private storage.

Then, whatever you planned to do with the file in res/raw you can do it in the local storage copy.

Comment: If it so, then i actually don't see a purpose of keeping the res/raw file. You can just work with files in the local up. Or is it just a temporary storage?

Comment: The use case would be that for some reason you need to provide that file with the installation. It could be a template for example. The app's local storage will become available when the app is installed and will be removed when then app is uninstalled. The user also can wipe the files in the app's local storage by clearing the data in settings -> apps -> click on the app -> clear data (or something like this)